# Non-saturated countable model

Tags: model-theory

Here is a problem in "Model Theory" (Exercise 2.3.20, Chang-Keisler 2012).

> In a countable language, let $T$ be a complete theory which is not
> $\omega$-categorical. Let $\Gamma_1, \cdots, \Gamma_n$ be consistent
> types over $T$. Show that $T$ has a countable model $\frak{A}$ which
> realizes $\Gamma_1, \cdots, \Gamma_n$ but is not saturated.

To prove it, it needs to show that a finite type can not be realized in $T$. But since each $\Gamma_i$ is realized in $T$, I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal U$ be a saturated model of $T$.

**Fact.** The following are equivalent for $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathcal U$ some arbitrary elements

0. $T$ is $\omega$-categorical
1. every elementary substructure of  $\mathcal U$ is $\omega$-saturated
2. every elementary substructure of $\mathcal U$ containing $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is $\omega$-saturated.

Assume the Fact (exercise).

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be realizations of $\Gamma_1,\dots,\Gamma_n$ in $\mathcal U$. If $T$ is not $\omega$-categorical, there is an elementary substructure $\frak A$ of $\mathcal U$  containing $a_1,\dots,a_n$ which is not saturated.

**Proof of the Fact**

(0$\Rightarrow$1) Negate $(1)$ and assume that $\frak A\preceq\mathcal U$ does not realize the consistent type $\Gamma$. By Löwenheim-Skolem we may assume $\frak A$ is countable. Again by Löwenheim-Skolem  there is a countable $\frak B\preceq\mathcal U$ that realizes $\Gamma$. As $\frak A, B$ are not isomorphic, $T$ is not $\omega$-categorical.

(1$\Rightarrow$2) Clear.

(2$\Rightarrow$0)
Any two countable $\frak A, B$ such that $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\frak A, B\preceq\mathcal U$ are saturated. Hence they are isomorphic over $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Then the theory Th$({\mathcal U}/a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is $\omega$-categorical. Then for every $k$ there are finitely many non equivalent formulas $\varphi(a_1,\dots,a_n,x_1,\dots,x_k)$.
In particular there are also  finitely many non equivalent formulas $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_k)$.

Comment: Indeed, my answer may be far from CK. I'll try to add more tomorrow.

Comment: I have added a proof of the fact. It is not in the language of CK (I am not familiar with it, it is a bit archaic), but I hope you are able to make sense of it.

Comment: The language is ok and does not have to the same as CK